# Python Dict: entry dependes on existing entry

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to add in a python dict a key/value, that is depenend of an existing key/value. Example

```
x = {}
x["length"] = 12
x["volume"] =x["lenght"] * 10
```

That works; but is there a possiblity to do that in one way (similar to that one, but that one does not work):

```
xx ={"length":12, "volume": xx["length"] *10}
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

```
xx ={"length":12, "volume": xx["length"] *10}
```

This won't work because xx is not defined and you are trying to access it before definition completes. Remember python is executed line by line. So this line tries to execute at once.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can ...

```
class mydict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        if key == 'volume':
            self[key] = vol = self['length'] * 10
            return vol

        raise KeyError(key)

md = mydict(length=12)

print('volume:', md['volume'])
print('length:', md['length'])
print('other:', md['other'])
```

Output:

```
volume: 120
length: 12
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./hola.py", line 37, in <module>
    print('other:', md['other'])
  File "./hola.py", line 31, in __missing__
    raise KeyError(key)  # to raise an Exception
KeyError: 'other'
```

Being the only drawback that you cannot use the `{}` notation, but you still have a `dict` (a subclass of it) and not a user defined class. Not 100% what you seem to want, but should do the trick.